# Accessing A MovieClip using a String Variable AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs3

I've a general question on accessing a MovieClip by using a variable.

Here's a super stripped down version of the code I'm trying to implement:

```
var mcVar:String = MC1;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eF);
function eF(e:Event):void{  
   if (BGMov.[mcVar].currentFrame >= 10){       
      BGMov.gotoAndStop(2);     
   }
}
```

Is this a possibility?
Any help is greatly appreciated!
Cheers,
Simon

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var mcVar:String = "MC1";

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eF);
function eF(e:Event):void{  
    if (BGMov[mcVar].currentFrame >= 10){       
        BGMov.gotoAndStop(2);     
    }
}
```

I believe you just need to make sure `mcVar` is a string and there is no dot before the square bracket. However this is untested as I haven't got Flash open right now.